# Failing to put message on ActiveMQ using JNDI lookup

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic, jndi, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to send a message using ActiveMQ from a JBoss EAP 7 Docker container to an ActiveMQ Docker container.
I have added the queue names to the standalone file, and I am resolving the queue name using JNDI lookup.

```
@Resource(name = "java:/jms/queueName")
```

The Connection factory is also being resolved via JNDI

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/activeMQConnectionFactory")
```

The class that is resolving these objects is annotated with

```
@Named("MyClassName")
@Stateless
```

and injected into another class.

My queue setup is

```
Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;

    try {
        connection = cf.createConnection();

        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(senderQueueName);
        connection.start();

        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText(payload);
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId.trim());
        message.setJMSExpiration(Long.parseLong(messageExpiryMillis));
        producer.send(message);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
```

I still cannot send a message to the queue, which is frustrating because if I hard code the queue name and connection factory, the application works successfully.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more information if needed.

> Edit

Queue setup in the standalone file is as follows:

```
<resource-adapter id="activemq-rar">
<archive>
    activemq-rar-5.15.6.rar
</archive>
<transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
<config-property name="ServerUrl">
    tcp://{{ activemq_host }}:{{ activemq_port }}{{ activemq_tcp_connection_options }}
</config-property>
<config-property name="UserName">
    {{ activemq_user }}
</config-property>
<config-property name="Password">
    {{ activemq_password }}
</config-property>
<config-property name="UseInboundSession">
    true
</config-property>
<connection-definitions>
    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory"
                            jndi-name="java:/jms/activeMQConnectionFactory" enabled="true"
                            use-java-context="true" pool-name="activeMQManagedConnectionFactory">
        <config-property name="UseInboundSession">
            false
        </config-property>
        <config-property name="MaximumRedeliveries">
            0
        </config-property>
        <xa-pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        </xa-pool>
        <recovery>
            <recover-credential>
                <user-name>recoveryName</user-name>
                <password>recoveryPassword</password>
            </recover-credential>
        </recovery>
    </connection-definition>
</connection-definitions>
<admin-objects>
    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/jms/q.requestQueueName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="RequestPool">
        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
            q.my.request.queue
        </config-property>
    </admin-object>
    <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/jms/q.responseQueueName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ResponsePool">
        <config-property name="PhysicalName">
            q.my.response.queue
        </config-property>
    </admin-object>
</admin-objects>
```

I am using Ansible to resolve the placeholders in the file. But when I debug the code, I see that the Connection factory and queue names are being resolved correctly.

I am not getting any errors in the server log files.

Comment: @JustinBertram I just updated the question with your requests.

Comment: When you debug the code can you see that the `java:/jms/activeMQConnectionFactory` connection factory you looked up has the right `brokerURL`?

Comment: It's correct. When I let the application run through, I log onto the ActiveMQ admin console, and see that the queue was created, with no messages being pushed onto it.

Comment: My only idea at this point is that maybe there's something going on with the underlying JTA transaction which the connection factory is being enlisted into when you look it up from JNDI (which the JCA resource adapter does automatically) vs. when you just instantiate it directly. Can you confirm that the JTA transaction is being committed properly?

Comment: @JustinBertram I'm not sure how to tell that, still new to ActiveMQ. But I will investigate and update my question if I find anything, Thanks for the help.